# SQL Query: comparison with condition

Tags: sql, filter, comparison, conditional-statements

I have a table which looks as follows (simplified):

**name | status**
app-1  | start
app-1  | run
app-1  | run
app-1  | run
app-1  | finish
app-2  | start
app-2  | run
app-2  | run

now, I would like to filter all apps, that have "start" for a status AND no "finish". For the example above, the result is supposed to be "app-2".

I have no clue how to do the comparison while additionally use a condition...it really gives me some hard time. I hope someone can help me with it?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select name from _table t1
  where t1.status = 'start'
    and not exists (
      select name from _table t2
         where t1.name = t2.name
          and t2.status = 'finish'
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE status = 'run' and name NOT IN
  (SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE status = 'finish')
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure which Relational Database you are using but the query will be similar:

```
Select AppStatus.Name
From (
      Select Name, Started, Finished
      Sum(Case When status = 'start' then 1 else 0 end) as Started,
      Sum(Case When status = 'finish' then 1 else 0 end) as Finished,
      From Table
      Group By Name
) as AppStatus
Where AppStatus.Started > 0 and AppStatus.Finished > 0
```

Update:
If you assume that all rows will begin with a start, and have zero or more runs and then a finish, this will also work and is much more simple!

```
Select Distinct(Name) 
From Table Where Name Not In (
    SELECT Name
    FROM Table
    WHERE Status = 'finish')
```